# How to launch an application with admin rights?

Tags: delphi

for delphi,

I want to run my application with admin rights on vista or win 7 is there a solution for this you may know ?

related question:

[Want to learn if my application has admin rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300390/want-to-learn-if-my-application-has-admin-rights)

thanks.

Comment: Then you should ask two questions ;)

Comment: Can you precise :
- if you want to run your application exe that has "embeded" admin rights ? 
- if the user can make a special manipulation (such SHIFT+right cliek) ?
- if each windows configuration of each computer can be changed or not ?
- if it is a durable or development solution you're looking for ?

Comment: @snowflake i asked two questions, because i think they are related. 
i simply want to change any windows settings like file access permissons..
if i can't run my application as administrator, then i want to warn user
to run application as administrator.

Comment: have seperated the questions. sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To run a program with admin rights I have this function which has worked for me so far.

```
procedure RunAsAdmin(const aFile: string; const aParameters: string = ''; Handle: HWND = 0);
var
  sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin                   
  FillChar(sei, SizeOf(sei), 0);

  sei.cbSize := SizeOf(sei);
  sei.Wnd := Handle;
  sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
  sei.lpVerb := 'runas';
  sei.lpFile := PChar(aFile);
  sei.lpParameters := PChar(aParameters);
  sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  if not ShellExecuteEx(@sei) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: hi, is this AunAsAdmin function recursive in nature... as I used this function but it is cyclic in nature and I had to end task in order to stop this.

Comment: Also, add ShellAPI to your uses (and Windows if not already present).